# HTML parsing with HTML::TokeParser::Simple

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I am parsing an HTML file with `HTML::TokeParser::Simple`. The HTML file has the content shown far below. My problem is, I am trying to ignore the JavaScript from showing up as text content. Example:

```
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
my $p = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new( 'test.html' );

while ( my $token = $p->get_token ) {
    next unless $token->is_text;
    print $token->as_is, "\n";
}
```

This prints the output as seen below:

```
Test HTML

<!--
  var form_submitted = 0;

  function submit_form() {
    [..]
  }
 //-->
```

---

**The actual HTML Document Content:**

```
<html>
<span>Test HTML</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  var form_submitted = 0;

  function submit_form() {
    [..]
  }
 //-->
</script>
</html>
```

How do I ignore the `JavaScript` tag contents from showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan through the token to ignore all open and close script tags. See below as used to resolved the issue.

```
   my $ignore=0;

   while ( my $token = $p->get_token ) {

      if ( $token->is_start_tag('script') ) {
         print $token->as_is, "\n";
         $ignore = 1;
         next;
      }
      if ( $token->is_end_tag('script') ) {
         $ignore = 0;
         print $token->as_is, "\n";
         next;
      }
      if ($ignore) {
         #Everything inside the script tag. Here you can ignore or print as is
         print $token->as_is, "\n";
      }
      else
      {  
          #Everything excluding scripts falls here handle as appropriate
          next unless $token->is_text;
          print $token->as_is, "\n";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the desired result. Comments are (correctly) not considered text by the version I have. Looks like you need to upgrade the modules you are using. (I used HTML::Parser 3.69 and HTML::TokeParser::Simple 3.15.)

```
>perl a.pl
Test HTML



>
```

You'll still have to process HTML entities and format the text usefully, the latter being quite difficult since you removed all formatting instruction. Your approach seems fatally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to use the `as_text` method.

```
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new();
    $tree->parse( $html );
    $tree->eof();
    $tree->elementify(); # just for safety
    my $text = $tree->as_text();
    $tree->delete;
```

I adapted this from the WWW::Mechanize module (http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) which has tons of convenience methods that can help you.  It basically acts as a web browser in an object.